# If a class calls another, can I put them in separate JAR files?

Tags: java, import, jar, include

Let's say I have two classes Airport and Airplane:

```
public class Airport
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Airplane a1 = new Airplane();
    }
}

public class Airplane
{
    int seats;
    public Airplane()
    {
        seats = 10;
    }
}
```

I want to put these classes in separate JAR files so that I can develop them independent of each other in future in case any issue comes up. Since `Airport` calls `Airplane` I have to import `Airplane` in the `Airport` source file. I was thinking of importing them in the project that I will use to call these classes. But even if I import both of them in project, there still are issues about resolves.

UPDATE: Can you give an example .classpath to accomplish this call hierarchy? I simply added JARs to the .classpath of Main Project but `Airport` complains that it can't find methods of `Airplane`.

[image: Call Tree of what I want to accomplish]

Comment: Assuming you want `Airplane` to be compiled in a different `.jar` file, once you have it, just add it to the classpath of the project containing your main `Airport` class. You can also package the dependency containing `Airplane` within the .jar file you end up with after packaging your main project, so you have a standalone jar.

Comment: There is `Airplane` project, 'Airport' project and the main project I use to call these(total 3). If I convert `Airport` and `Airplane` to separate JARs(`Airport` gets compile error since I have not supplied the JAR for Airport cause I want to do it in the upper project for convenience) and include them to classpath in main project,  `Airport` complains that it can't find `Airplane` methods.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can import `Airplane` into `Airport` even if these classes are in different JARs. However, both JARs must be present in the classpath.

Comment: @Klypnos Sorry, I don't quite understand, an example of what?

Comment: I added all entries to classpath but there still is "Unresolved compilation" error. I have a project which calls Airport and Airport calls Airplane. I've added jar files to project classpath.